# Converting C to MIPS

Tags: mips, cpu, instructions

I am writing a program in MIPS but cannot wrap my head around writing the following statement below. How do I write a logical statement like this in MIPS instruction set?

```
return a > b ? a : b;
```

Comment: Look up `SLT` and `BEQ` in the MIPS instruction set reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `return` : return some value to the callee (if expression presents).
- `A ? B : C` : This is conditional operator. If `A` is true (non-zero), `B` is evaluated. Otherwise, `C` is evaluated.

If `a` and `b` are signed 32-bit integers, it should be like this:

```
# assuming
# a = $t0
# b = $t1
# return value = $v0

slt   $t2, $t1,   $t0     # $t2 = (b < a)
beq   $t2, $zero, nottrue # if (!(a > b)) goto nottrue
addui $v0, $t0,   $zero   # return value = a (not harmful even if executed when jump is taken)
jr  $ra                   # return
sll $zero, $zero, 0       # nop: prevent instruction after branch from being executed
nottrue:
addui $v0,   $t1,   $zero # return value = b
jr    $ra                 # return
sll   $zero, $zero, 0     # nop: prevent instruction after branch from being executed
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, you're a wizard

Answer (score -1):

First of all break it in simple if statements, MIPS is an Assembly Language so all that won't work if they are complicated,remember the fact that your brain is not a compiler so try not to write complex code.